# Replication new article being added to transactional replication, snapshot generated but not applied, no errors

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2016, transactional-replication

We have replication setup on two 2016 servers. Distribution and publisher are on the same instance. We have transactional replication running at this time with no issue. We are trying to add a new table to replication and these are the steps we followed:

1. Going to properties of the publisher. Articles. Checking off the new table to be added. Clicking ok, does not prompt to reinitialize (which is what we want).
2. Go to replication monitor, start the snapshot agent to take partial snapshot. In this scenario one article is generated (one table is chosen).

after this nothing happens. Table does not appear in subscriber database.

allow-anonymous is false and immediate-sync is false.

Am I missing a step or could it be a different issue?

Working on SQL server 2016 SP2-CU8 installed on both servers.

Comment: I ran the query from this blog:http://www.dharmendrakeshari.com/add-new-articles-existing-transactional-replication-without-initializing-old-articles/

The article in question states that it is active (published). It's like replication thinks that it's published but it's not on the replicated server.

Comment: To further complicate things. The log reader agent is throwing errors now. Stating the table doesn't exist..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check the following two options of the published article: Create Schemas at Subscriber and Action if Object is in use. The first one must be set to true and the second one you can set to Drop and Re-create if your application logic allows this. If you cannot allow to drop the destination table then at least the first option must be set to true for the replication agent to automatically create the destination table if it is missing. See the below image for the mentioned options:

[image: Article properties]

HTH

Comment: Thanks Andrew I will check this out and let reply back if that was the fix!

Comment: It would seem that is already setup the way you recommended. What we are doing now is recreating replication on a test server to see and try to see if we can recreate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and fixed it by changing the allow_anonymous and immediate_sync properties back to TRUE and then turned back FALSE again.

That worked like a charm.